# What Data Structure to use while storing relationship and weight?

Tags: python, data-structures

I need to represent relationships in Python and I am looking for some suggestion about what I can use and how.

relationship represented as :

`[(item1, relation) -> item2] -> weight`

It says that when item1 and item2 have given relationship between them then weight of this tuple is 1. For example `[(cars, has parts) -> wheels] -> 1`

For those of you who are familiar with C++, know that we can use something like

```
map<pair<int,int>, map<int,int> > ok;
```

I can use nested dictionaries like `{item1, {item2, {relation, weight}}}`. But that will be very ugly and also, confusing for anyone who will come across it in future.

So how to do it in Python in a cleaner way? A sample code will be very helpful

Answer (score 1):

You can use Objects and Classes to represent complex data structures, then use Arrays to make it a collection.

Here is an example I wrote and tested in Python 3.6

```
>>> class WeightedRelationship:
...     def __init__(self, item1, item2, relationship, weight):
...             self.item1 = item1
...             self.item2 = item2
...             self.relationship = relationship
...             self.weight = weight
```

Using your cars/wheels relationship example, you can make an instance of this class:

```
>>> cars = WeightedRelationship(item1 = "Car", item2 = "Wheel", relationship = "has parts", weight = 1)
```

And then you can use an array to store multiple instances.

Answer (score 1):

You can maybe use simple python dictionary (like a json object):

```
{'item1': 'car', 'relation': 'has parts', 'item2': 'wheels', 'weight': 1}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you require, but you can store anonymous functions as keys or values in dictionaries. I'm choosing a numeric example for simplicity.

```
d = [(1, lambda x, y: x+y==4, 3),(1, lambda x, y: x+y==5, 7)]
d2 = {k: k[1](k[0], k[2]) for k in d}

# d2
# {(1, <function __main__.<lambda>>, 3): True,
#  (1, <function __main__.<lambda>>, 7): False}
```

The `lambda` functions can do anything, e.g. if you had a dictionary mapping car to list of all parts, then you can define `lambda x, y: y in car_parts_dict[x]` or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers people have given, you mentioned this C++ code:

```
map<pair<int,int>, map<int,int> > ok;
```

You can do the exact same thing in Python if you have `ok` be a dictionary where keys are tuples containing 2 `int`s and where values are also tuples containing 2 `int`s, e.g.:

```
ok = {(item1,relation):(item2,weight)}
```

However, I agree with the other answers that nested dictionaries are the cleanest way to go:

```
ok = {item1:{relation:{item2:weight}}}
```

so you can access the weight via:

```
ok[item1][relation][item2]
```